# Find out what is being cached in memory by Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, cache, task-manager

Windows maintains a memory cache of frequently accessed items:

[image: Task Manager - Performance - Physics Memory]

Is it possible to view the cache?

Can I see what files and what portion of each file are being cached?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible, but willing to be proven wrong ... this would be a huge security risk as you could view the memory contents of processes that you don't own.

Answer (score -1):

You can use RAMMap from microsoft windows website. Here's the link to it [DOWNLOAD RamMap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap)

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.